# fontspec: Defining a new font family using TeX Gyre Pagella causes error

Tags: fonts, fontspec, font-encodings

I just updated my packages through the MikTeX console, and when I try to define a new font family with TeX Gyre Pagella, I get a mysterious error (below). Just defining the new font family leads to the error; it's not necessary to use it anywhere. Commenting out the `\newfontfamily` macro or replacing TeX Gyre Pagella with something else allows it to compile. This did not occur before the update just now.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\myfamily}{TeX Gyre Pagella} 
% Comment out or replace with Times New Roman to compile

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

`Runaway argument?
76543210\q_stop end \exp_args:NNf \group_end: \iow_log:n {\tl_to_str:N \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \__iow_wrap_end_chunk:w.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> ./test.tex`

Any ideas? (Also, I'm not entirely sure if I need `fontenc` here, but the same error happens even without including it.)

Comment: Oh, I should also mention that setting the main font to TeX Gyre Pagella with `\setmainfont` works fine. It's only defining a new font family with it that causes the issue.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/456257

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is due to a bug that has already been removed

Comment: @egreg On one hand I agree that this question is off-topic since it is about a resolved bug, on the other hand it might be useful for MikTeX users to leave the question open until the update arrives in MikTeX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**: As of 2018-10-24 0:00 midnight (EST, may be earlier), the 2018-10-19 `l3kernel` has made its way to MiKTeX, so additional tweaking is *no longer nessessary*.

---

**Old answer if you are using the 2018-10-17 `l3kernel`**: MiKTeX was really late updating a [bug fix](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/491) from the `l3kernel` package. So we must wait until MiKTeX updates its repository.

In the mean time, since there were only two lines of code changed, you could

1. Go to your local directory: `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel`.
2. Copy the file `expl3-code.tex`.
3. Paste it into your *working* directory.
4. **Replace** line 10665

   ```
   \or: \use_none:nnnnnnn
   ```

   with this line

   ```
   \or: \__iow_wrap_line_seven:nnnnnnn
   ```
5. **Add** this line

   ```
   \cs_new:Npn \__iow_wrap_line_seven:nnnnnnn #1#2#3#4#5#6#7 { \exp_stop_f: }
   ```

   before line 10669

   ```
   \cs_new:Npn \__iow_wrap_line_end:NnnnnnnnN #1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9 % <- So this becomes line 10670
   ```

This is how I get around using packages affected by the 2018-10-17 `l3kernel` update. As soon as MiKTeX has the 2018-10-19 `l3kernel` update, everything should be back to normal.

Comment: For reference, I opened an issue at the MikTeX packaging tracker to make sure that the update does not go unnoticed: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/58

Comment: The update made it to MikTeX tonight/this morning (UTC), so if one runs an update now the fixed version should be installed.